# Border in HTML (vertical line)

Tags: html, css, border

How would I create a border around the border of my webpage like the one here?

http://www.callieschweitzer.com/

I tried doing a horizontal rule but struggled aligning it with a vertical rule... I feel like there is a simpler way however. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parentDiv{
width:60%;
border:2px solid #DDDDDD;
padding:10%;
margin:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv"></div>
```

Comment: That is my website ^ the link is in the middle of the page. How would I make it cover the entire thing? This is what I have .parentDiv{
width:90%;
border:1px solid #000000;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
height: 100%;
}

Comment: use : .parentDiv {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

Comment: floating-box inside parentDiv

Comment: #about {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

Comment: #profile {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 23%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151794/discussion-between-farhad-bagherlo-and-sarah-h).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the content of your page is in a container  that has, for example, a css class "page-border" assigned to it, this would be the css:

```
.page-border
{
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```